# Error in Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2 while upgrading application from jdeveloper 11.1.1,7,1

Tags: oracle-adf

I was trying to upgrade my application from 11g to 12c. In that i am getting an error.

```
<org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl> <ViewHandlerImpl> <_isTimestampCheckEnabled> <Apache Trinidad is running with time-stamp checking enabled. This should not be used in a production environment. See the org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION property in WEB-INF/web.xml> 
<org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.util.FrameBustingUtils> <FrameBustingUtils> <_getFrameBustingString> <The framebusting context param 'oracle.adf.view.rich.security.FRAME_BUSTING' has been deprecated. Please change your web.xml to use 'org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.security.FRAME_BUSTING' instead. The legal values are 'always', 'never', and 'differentOrigin'. If you were setting the value of 'oracle.adf.view.rich.security.FRAME_BUSTING' to 'differentDomain', then please note that you should set 'org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.security.FRAME_BUSTING' to 'differentOrigin'.> 
<oracle.adf.view> <UIXRegion> <_logNullValueMessage> <The expression "#{bindings.AddTypeBTF1.regionModel}" that was specified for the RegionModel "value" attribute of the region component with id ":pt1:r1" evaluated to null. Using an empty RegionModel instead.> 
<oracle.adf.view> <UIXRegion> <_logNullValueMessage> <The expression "#{bindings.AddTypeBTF1}" evaluated to "".
The expression "#{bindings}" evaluated to "".
> 
<org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.style.xml.parse.StyleSheetDocument> <StyleSheetDocument> <_resolveStyleNode> <Circular dependency detected in style af|dvt-timeline> 
<Sep 19, 2017, 12:48:00,384 PM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:50,050 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
```

This is my page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>


<f:view>
    <af:document id="d1" title="PMS">
      <af:form id="f1">
       <af:pageTemplate viewId="/PMS/Template/PMSTemplate.jspx" id="pt1">
          <f:facet name="Content">
        <af:region value="#{bindings.AddTypeBTF1.regionModel}" id="r1"/>
        </f:facet>
        </af:pageTemplate>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

This is binding of the page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pageDefinition xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adfm/uimodel"
                version="11.1.1.65.57" id="PMSTypeMasterPageDef"
                Package="PMS.Pages">
  <parameters/>
  <executables>
    <variableIterator id="variables"/>
    <taskFlow id="AddTypeBTF1"
              taskFlowId="/PMS/TaskFlows/AddTypeBTF.xml#AddTypeBTF"
              activation="deferred"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller/binding"/>
  </executables>
  <bindings/>
</pageDefinition>
```

There is no warning in the page or else in the pagedef.
i tried to clean my application as well as removed all cache and useless stuff from my PC. Still it's not working.

I asked my colleague about this issue. they have faces the similar one. and it was solved by cleaning the application and they have restarted the Jdeveloper.
But same is not working with me.

I searched on the internet. many sites suggest that there might be no entry in the pagedef. but i can find entry of taskflow there as well.

Comment: In doubt you could try to delete the jdevelopper config data in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\ to ensure the issue isn't with jdeveloper. (it will recreate the default config at next startup)

Comment: Done that. Still no change in the error and console

Answer (score 0):

```
  <context-param>
<description>If this parameter is true, there will be an automatic check of the modification date of your JSPs, and saved state will be discarded when JSP's change. It will also automatically check if your skinning css files have changed without you having to restart the server. This makes development easier, but adds overhead. For this reason this parameter should be set to false when your application is deployed.</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
```